# Why do inserted photos not stay where I put them in Openoffice Writer 4.0?

Tags: openoffice, photos

I am trying to write an illustrated memoir of a recent trip, inserting photos into the text, sometimes several photos per page. Once my document gets to be more than about 10 pages, the photos seem to stray from the place where I inserted them, even though I have anchored them to the page, or even to the paragraph. This seems to happen when I resize the photos and then place them where I wish. I sometimes go back to a previous section and add photos, and then get into more trouble. This is very frustrating.

What can I do to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could try *protecting* image properties like position and/or size. To do so simply right-click on an image and select *Picture*. Then head to the *Options* tab and check your preferred protection settings in the *Protect* section:

[image]